# image zoom frame position using class selector in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zooming

Please take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2dWWx/2/)

I got the image magnifying plugin Leroy Zoom from this [site](https://github.com/edison/leroy-zoom). I have trouble making it work with multiple images on the same page. The zoom frame is fixed at a certain position and won't dynamically move next to any image on hover. Is there a way to make the zoom frame's position correspond to the hovered image?

HTML:

```
<div class="area"><a href="#" class="demo-trigger" data-medium-url="jpg" data-large-url="jpg">
    <img src="jpg" />
    </a>
</div>

<div class="area"><a href="#" class="demo-trigger" data-medium-url="jpg" data-large-url="jpg">
    <img src="jpg" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Executive Script:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {

       $(".demo-trigger").each(function(){
            var area = $(this).closest('.area')
            $(this).leroyZoom({
            zoomTop: 200, // Zoom frame distance from top in pixels
            zoomLeft: 160, // Zoom frame distance from left in pixels
            parent: area    
           });
       });
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to css

```
.area {
    position: relative,
}
```

Ten change zoomTop from 200 to 0 in you executive script.

Here is working version:
http://jsfiddle.net/2dWWx/13/